# how to create subdomains in apache(xampp) server?

Tags: apache, web, xampp, subdomain

I've trying to create subdomain in my local xampp installation for some time.
I tried editing my httpd.conf file and I entered the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /ecommerce
ServerName ecomm.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

I also edited my windows hosts file and entered:
127.0.0.1 ecomm.localhost

But when I type 'ecomm.localhost' in my firefox it gives me:
Access forbidden!!!
Can please anybody help me out? What exactly I'm doing wrong? I'm fairly new to this.
I simply want to create multiple folders in my 'htdocs' folder and use them as different websites with subdomain. For example:
c:\xampp\htdocs\mainSite   ----->    mainSite.com or mainSite.localhost
c:\xampp\htdocs\subSite    ----->    subSite.mainSite.com or subSite.mainSite.localhost

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this :

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "C:\path\to\ecommerce">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName ecomm.localhost
ServerAlias www.ecomm.localhost
DocumentRoot "C:\path\to\ecommerce"
</VirtualHost>
```

Yes you edited your hosts file correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jigar. I tried editing my httpd.conf with the above code but it still did not work. Firefox says:"Access forbidden" for ecomm.localhost and "could not find" for www.ecomm.localhost. I'll try the Ampps and see if it works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry I just notices you are using Windows. So replace `/ecommerce` to `"C:\path\to\ecommerce"`

Comment: Hey Jigar Thanks. It worked. I installed Ampps as you said and the first thing I did in the control panel was to set password. After that when I pointed my firefox to 'localhost/ampps' nothing happens. The address bar says "http://localhost/ampps/index.php?act=login" but nothing is displayed. Can you help please? I am able to see websites in 'www' folder but not able to see admin control panel.

Comment: try this http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Category:FAQs#Accessing_Admin.2FEnduser_Panel_gives_a_Blank_Page open a support ticket here if you are facing any issue http://www.ampps.com/support

Comment: Thanks Jigar I was able to resolve the problem by reinstalling Ampps. Thanks again for your support.

Comment: Ampps = USELESS for setting up sub domains

Comment: Is there any way to create subdomain in window + XAMPP without restarting Apache services ?

Comment: @ChintanGor you can look at graceful restart `apachectl -k graceful` (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/stopping.html#graceful)

Comment: @Jigar Do i also have to edit `hosts` file in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`

Comment: Yes @RajeevRanjanSharma, for domain to resolve to an IP we need an entry in `hosts` file. e.g. `127.0.0.1    ecomm.localhost`

Answer (score 12):

In addition to atabak's answer:

Go to Apache > Conf > Extra -> "httpd-vhosts.conf" file and add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/subdomain"
ServerName subdomain.localhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Go to C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc -> "hosts" file and add:

```
127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost
```

from [Setting Up Multiple Subdomains Using Xampp](http://www.codingcereal.com/2011/05/setting-up-multiple-subdomains-in-your-localhost-using-xampp)
/

Comment: httpd-vhosts.conf is missing?

Answer (score 4):

In xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf file add these line at the bottom of the file for subdomain support :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/sandbox"
   ServerName sandbox.localhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file add these line at the bottom of the file :

```
127.0.0.1    sandbox.localhost.com
```

After that re-start the xampp server and open a new tab, write in the address bar

```
sandbox.localhost.com
```

Then you will see the output of index.php file which was in the sandbox folder

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Paste at the bottom of the httpd-vhost.conf file at xampp > Apache > Conf > Extra. Make sure not to comment any vitualhost tag you're adding or you get "Attempting to start Apache" error when you restart server.. foodporch is the name of my subdomain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory  "c:/xampp/htdocs">
       Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/foodporch"
    ServerName foodporch.localhost
    <Directory  "c:/xampp/htdocs/foodporch">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Remember to add this line to end of host file at C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc ->
`127.0.0.1 foodporch.localhost.com`

Answer (score 2):

in httpd.xampp.conf file add this line for subdomain support :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/subdomain"
ServerName subdomain.localhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

then add :
windows hosts file and entered: `127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost`

work for me

Answer (score 0):

To improve on this answer for windows folks.
To enable actual saving of hosts file in windows:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc -> 127.0.0.1 subdomain.localhost.com
you must first open notepad as administrator or else
windows wont save the hosts file because system files require administrative
permission.

So first on start menu, find notepad, Right click on the icon.
Choose `Run as administrator`. Then open the hosts file. This will allow you to update the hosts file without adding any extensions.