# htaccess rule to redirect to a dynamic subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

we manage over 70 properties and each of their websites runs from the same php code with a database controlling the differences. I need to write a redirect for a specific occasion and I don't know how to create variables in .htaccess.

for example:
http://www.firstproperty.com/banquet becomes http://banquet.firstproperty.com
and
http://www.secondproperty.com/banquet becomes http://banquet.secondproperty.com

I am not sure if I should do this as a "redirect" or a "RewriteCond/RewriteRule"

This is my .htaccess now ( it removes index.php from codeigniter friendly urls )

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

redirect /joinTeam.php /index.php/prop/join_team

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to manage the redirection at the application level? (ie. check and redirect on the index.php)

Comment: Not in this situation. The main site (www.firstproperty.com) which is CodeIgniter is a different application than the banquet application. Since I harvest the propertyNumber from the URL, I need the "firstproperty" part to be in the URL that arrives at the banquet application.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt that a subdomain? in my opinion you should get into httpd.conf and not htaccess to manage that. Or am i wrong? wait a bit for further expertise comments in here. some work done here already it might help you out: [how to create subdomains in apache(xampp) server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086408/how-to-create-subdomains-in-apachexampp-server) hope it helps.

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory /banquet>
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName banquet.firstproperty.com/
ServerAlias www.banquet.firstproperty.com/
DocumentRoot /banquet
</VirtualHost>
```