# How to check out a different repository url into my existing working copy

Tags: svn, path, working-copy

Here's the scenario - I hope this makes sense.

I have multiple projects in Subversion, and I have apache installed on my windows machine.

I currently have one of the projects checked out to my htdocs directory that I was working on.

I've now finished working on that project, and want to check out a different project to the htdocs directory to work on.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: What you need to do is to checkout every project to it's own folder (under httdocs or whatever) and instruct Apache to point different URLs to diferrent physical paths. Meaning, what you need is correct Apache configuration, SVN can not solve your problem. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086408/how-to-create-subdomains-in-apachexampp-server

Comment: Got it - I'd seen that solution around, but wasn't sure that it was the only solution.  Thanks!